# How to make Future counter?

Tags: rust, future

I'm willing to `impl` a simple `Future` counter, but smth goes decidedly wrong about it. Without any use of `Context` the following programme would just block forever;

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::task::{Poll, Context};
use std::pin::Pin;
use futures::executor::block_on;

struct MyStruct {
    counter: u32
}

impl Future for MyStruct {
    type Output = String;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        if self.counter == 5 {
            Poll::Ready(self.counter.to_string())
        } else {
            unsafe {
                Pin::get_unchecked_mut(self).counter += 1;
            }
//            cx.waker().wake();
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ms = MyStruct{counter: 0};
    block_on(ms);
}
```

I imagine that I have to postpone somehow a call of `Waker`, but it's not that straightforward. So I wonder, how to `wake` it in the most simple form?

Comment: Not sure I understand the goal. A future doesn't yield multiple results, so even if your `poll()` worked correctly, it'd be no different than immediately returning `Poll::Ready("5")`.

Comment: @kmdreko, I would like to make it being polled several times until it is resolved with `Poll::Ready(...)`

Comment: But why? Or is this just a learning exercise?

Comment: @kmdreko, just self-learning experince) In ordinary implementation of Future there are sockets or some other fds, so the whole magic is within the `epoll` syscall. It does not draw much interest with so much extra things. So I would like to build a concise example without any sockets involved.

Comment: @kmdreko, I can hazard a guess, that it might be achieved by setting a system timer, but how to pass the `Waker` there and do the trick?

Comment: @kmdreko, Or, maybe, I have to tell it to the `futures` somehow?

Comment: Your code (with calling `.wake()` properly each time) [does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=050893e0dcfc8323eabfc6caf3cb8cf8) in that it will be polled to completion. At the most fundamental level, calling `.wake()` will tell the executor handling the future to `.poll()` again.

Comment: @kmdreko, Hah, I have not thought that the `Waker` may be just cloned and then be moved around freely. My shame, ha. Thanks!!

Comment: [It's better to use `wake_by_ref()` if you don't need to store the waker](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fe93fb78929323f0da45143cce29dda). But I fail to understand your goal: _when_ do you want the future to wake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`.wake_by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.Waker.html#method.wake_by_ref). Waking the waker will tell the executor that is handling the `Future` to be `.poll()`'d again:

```
impl Future for MyStruct {
    type Output = String;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        if self.counter == 5 {
            Poll::Ready(self.counter.to_string())
        } else {
            unsafe {
                Pin::get_unchecked_mut(self).counter += 1;
            }
            cx.waker().wake_by_ref();
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

So your implementation will always ask to be immediately re-polled. I'll note that this is logically no different than simply returning `Poll::Ready("5".to_string())` on the first invocation since there's no asynchronous work being done here. Because of that, there's no reason for it to be a `Future` at all.

Comment: I'd say it's more like looping (or recursing) then returning `Poll::Ready`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, agreed. But I imagine it is possible to postpone it by a timer somehow, after returning `Poll::Pending`? Despite the fact that `std` does not provide for timers ...

Comment: @unegare Did you mean to comment on your question? Anyway, that's what I asked: when do you want to wake up?

Comment: @unegare then you'd need to get into the "magic" of syscalls or other mechanisms to call `.wake()` at a different point in time.

Comment: @unegare If all you want is to learn you can spawn a thread that will sleep then call the waker. This is going to be embarrassingly non-performant but it is enough to grasp the concepts.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, Yes, my target is the comprehension of the process. it'll suit me well Thanks!

Comment: @unegare [here's an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa3f2a65dd6aa5f181cd533ac24d2788) that works as Chayim described and will therefore take 5 seconds to complete.